# So I have this code for trading view that my friend send me asking for help. (Pine Script V5)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

The error is occurring with this line:

```
strategy.position_size("Buy", size=positionSize)
```

Ive looked it up and I'm not sure if it is even possible to use strategy.position_size.

Ive tried doing `strategy.position_size = ("Buy", size=positionSize)`, I've also tried defining `strategy.position_size` as a function but that also gave me errors. There's also `strategy.position_size => ("Buy", size=positionSize)` which I saw was supposed to work but didn't.

Comment: We need to see your code to help. See [MCVE] for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`strategy.position_size` is a built-in variable that should only be used for retrieving the current position direction and size. See the reference manual:

> [strategy.position_size](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dposition_size)
>
> Direction and size of the current market position. If the value is > 0, the market position is long. If the value is < 0, the market position is short. The absolute value is the number of contracts/shares/lots/units in trade (position size).

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you wanted to size your position, you would have to do it via commands like `strategy.entry` or `strategy.order`.